# How to make the dollar sign appear right next to the sum in python?

Tags: python

I am doing a simple program in python for my class, and I basically have it down except I can't figure out how to make the dollar sign appear right next to the sum without leaving a space. This is my code:

```
item1 = input("Enter price of first item: $");
item2 = input("Enter price of second item:$");
item3 = input("Enter price of third item: $");
total = (item1 + item2 + item3);
print("The total of the three items is:$", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print("The total of the three items is:${}".format(total))
```

If in python 3.6 or above, you can also use `f-Strings`:

```
print(f"The total of the three items is:${total}")
```

The "old fashioned way" would be to use the `%s` formatter:

```
print("To total of the three items is:$%s" % total)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked